# How to create an instance of a class from a string name of the instance?

Tags: python, oop

I would like to create several instances of a Class, I tried to make a for loop to name them differently.
Something like this, which doesn't work because the instance name is not supposed to be a string:

```
class A:
    pass

for i in range(10):
    "a"+str(i) = A()
```

Here the result I expect is 10 instances of the class A named: a0, a1, ... , a9.

How should I do?

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's right, never thank about this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionaries,

```
classes = {}
for i in range(10):
    classes[f"a{i}"]  = A()
```

Then you can access the class instance like this `classes["a7"]`.

Comment: I like the idea, I didn't know it was possible this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i can think in two ways.
The trash way and a good way

Thrash:

```
class A:
    pass

for i in range(10):
    eval("a"+str(i)) = A()
```

Good:

```
class A:
    pass

a= []
for i in range(10):
    a[i] = A()
```

Comment: I tried the first, **eval()** doesn't work. For the second it's a good idea, I replaced **a[i]** with **a.append()** and it worked. Thank you

Comment: eval only work for testing purposes i runned here and it worked. but append is a better ideia and works like a[i]

Comment: Ok, I don't know that much about eval(), but for the list I got an index out of range error, that's why I changed it to append

Comment: its becouse you must to start from 0 and when you use range you start from 1

Comment: Is it not because when created, the list has no "slot" available? I mean it's length is equal to 0.

Comment: ok, its nice to know